# Check if a file is setuid root in Python

Tags: python, file, setuid, stat

I'm trying to check if a file has the setuid bit in Python.

[The stat doc](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) mentions a `S_ISUID` function but it only works with `os.chmod()`, not to actually read the setuid bit. It also lists `S_IMODE`, but I have no idea how to interpret it.

How can I easily check if a file as the setuid root bit set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

stat.S_ISUID is the mode bit for 'setuid'. You compare the stat result's mode to see if it contains that bit:

```
>>> ping = os.stat('/bin/ping')
>>> ping.st_mode & stat.S_ISUID
2048
>>> echo = os.stat('/bin/echo')
>>> echo.st_mode & stat.S_ISUID
0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I find the example in the manual doesn't make this very clear as all the examples they give use things like `S_ISDIR(mode)` so I was trying `S_ISUID(mode)` and it didn't work.